# xamarin android - add admob ads problems

Tags: android, xamarin.android, admob

When I added the Google Play ad component to my app, I received the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   Manager     1   Active
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl-ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Basement' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Ads' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.   Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.1.1.jar doesn't exist.   Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Tasks' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Tasks\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.   Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Gass' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Gass\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Ads' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads\9.4.0\content directory.  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Clearcut' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Clearcut\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\content directory.  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite\9.4.0\content directory. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\content directory. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Tasks\9.4.0\content directory.   Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Gass\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Clearcut\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Clearcut\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Gass' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Gass\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Tasks' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Tasks\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Ads Lite' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\43DC07E5A9A61485CEDA94D8006556F2.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Ads Lite' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\content directory. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads\9.4.0\content directory. Manager         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50.zip is not a valid zip file  Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl-ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Tasks\9.4.0\content directory.   Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl-ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Gass\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Basement' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\9.4.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https:// dl ssl .google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r32.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\9.4.0\content directory.    Manager         
Error       Please install package: 'GPS Clearcut' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\MASRI\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Clearcut\9.4.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist. Manager
```

I don't understand why I'm getting so many errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package: 'GPS Base', available in SDK installer. All of these errors seem to arise from your code calling GPS Base SDK functions, which causes errors because you have not installed it yet.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that ? :)